# Pass Content To Function of Another Module in Python

Tags: python, memory, arguments, argument-passing, saxparser

I am using SAX Parser. I am trying to send the 'content' I retrieved using below code:

After checking the startElement and endElement, I have the below code:

```
def characters(self, content):  
   text =  format.formatter(content)
```

this format.formatter is expected to read this data that I sent as 'content' for any processing like removing junk characters etc and return it. I do that by using string.replace function:

```
    remArticles = {' ! ':'', ' $ ':''}

    for line in content:
        for i in remArticles:
            line= line.replace(i, remArticles[i])
        #FormattedFileForIndexing.write(line)
            return line
```

However the output is not coming up as expected.

It will be great if some one can help on this.

source will some thing like:

"Oh! That's lots and 1000s of $$$$"

Expected: Oh That's lot of 1000s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over each character not each line:

```
def characters(content):
    remArticles = {'!': '', '$': ''} # remove spaces from " ! "
    for i in remArticles:
         content = content.replace(i, remArticles[i])
    return content
```

You are also trying to match `!` and `$` with spaces around them which according to your expected output is incorrect.

```
In [6]: content =  "Oh! That's lots and 1000s of $$$$"

In [7]: characters(content)
Out[7]: "Oh That's lots and 1000s of "
```

Just using replace is the most efficient option:

```
In [20]: timeit characters(content)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 746 ns per loop

In [21]: timeit format_this(content)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.57 µs per loop
```

Comment: Actually remArticles = {'!': '', '$': ''}  was a sample. I have many keys in this and it's quite huge. I am giving a sample gist:

remArticles = {' a ':'', ' the ':'', ' and ':'', ' an ':'', '&  nbsp;':'', 'imagesize':'', 'image_seal':'', 'image_caption':'', 'svg|mapsize':'', ']]':'', ' ]] ':'', '[[':'', ' [[ ':'', 'ca':'', 'io':'', 'ht':'', 'ht':'', 'nl':'',
               'pl':'', 'pt':'', 'vo':'', '{':'', '[':'', '*':'', '|':'',}

I made changes as per your suggestion, it works upto certain extent. Meaning, some of the alphabets are getting replaced, but not the }} or ]] or | etc..

Comment: is that your full remArticles? You also have duplicate keys in your dict

Comment: I also checked the code against `]} `etc.. and it works fine, as I said already `" ! "` is not equal to `"!"`

Comment: Hold on, after your recent update about iterating over each character and not not each line, that works, but takes lot of time.. do you use any tool to calculate the performance?

Comment: what version of python are you using? I use the timeit module in ipython to time code.

Comment: string operations are costly so obviously depending on how much data you have it could take quite a while, what are you working on?

Comment: Ok. Is there any thing that we can do to convert  to some thing else to enhance the performance?

Comment: for single characters yes you could use str.translate which would be very fast, you could split it into two parts use translate for single characters and only use the dict approach for multi character replacements. There is no easy really fast  way to do what you want though

Comment: It does not work today. It wouldn't replace they data from remArticles

Comment: @ Padraic I was trying the same today. But does not work. Also I needed some additional clarification. Referring to what you have stated:

"You are iterating over each character not each line"

Comment: Without seeing what you are trying to change it is impossible to help you, what I mean by each character is if you iterate over a string you don't get each word you get each character

Comment: have an xml file with page, title, id and text tags.

Comment: If you use the code as in my answer there should be no problem. Add an example of the input and your code to pastebin and post the link

Answer (score 0):

Your `return line` is excessively aligned, assuming your Q is showing your actual code, so you end after the first replacement.  De-indent that `return` by 4 spaces, so it aligns with the `for` keyword, not with the body of the `for` loop.

Added: `{' ! ':'', ' $ ':''}` matches exclamation marks and dollar signs only if they have spaces before and after them.  But then the OP says a sample input is `"Oh! That's lots and 1000s of $$$$"` -- **no** spaces before and after those punctuation marks, so nothing will be replaced.

Comment: Looks like after the indent is de-indented, it seems to work. But still my output is not good..The returned output data is clear. The sentences are completely gone and I see some letters here and there...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def format_this(content):
    bad_keys = {'!', '$'}
    return "".join([element for element in content if element not in bad_keys])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    content = "Oh! That's lots and 1000s of $$$$"
    formatted_content = format_this(content)
    print formatted_content

>>> Oh That's lots and 1000s of
```