# Pass Content To Method of Another Module in Python and read Word by Word

Tags: python, saxparser

I am using SAX Parser. I am trying to send the 'content' I retrieved using below code:

After checking the startElement and endElement, I have the below code:

```
def characters(self, content):  
   text =  format.formatter(content)
```

this format.formatter is expected to read this data that I sent as 'content' for any processing like removing junk characters etc and return it. I do that by using string.replace function:

remArticles = {' ! ':'', ' $ ':''}

for line in content:
    for i in remArticles:
        line= line.replace(i, remArticles[i])
    #FormattedFileForIndexing.write(line)
        return line

However the output is not coming up as expected.

It will be great if some one can help on this.

**source will some thing like:**

"Oh! That's lots and 1000s of $$$$"

**Expected:** Oh That's lot of 1000s

I have tried:

```
def characters(content):
    remArticles = {'!': '', '$': ''} # remove spaces from " ! "
    for i in remArticles:
         content = content.replace(i, remArticles[i])
    return content
```

But it didn't help. It wouldn't replace. This I thought it worked earlier, but does not look like it is working today:
[Pass Content To Function of Another Module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091913/pass-content-to-function-of-another-module-in-python)

Comment: Is your content is a string type?

Comment: @latheef possible. I am using sax parser and the contentText comes from content in 
`def characters(self, content):`

Comment: can you use other string methods on contents?

Comment: No when I say print " "+content+" " it errors

Comment: Yeah..then check `type(content)` also paste the error

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my earlier update. It won't error.